# Powershell replace operator unexpectedly replaces twice when using asterisk metacharacter

Tags: regex, powershell

Using powershell on Windows, when I use the following simple regular expression to remove any space characters at the end of the string and also append a period, I get duplication of the replacement string when there are spaces. Almost as if the spaces and the end-of-line is matched separately:

```
PS C:\>  "walk along the edge"   -replace ' *$',"s."
walk along the edges.
PS C:\>  "walk along the edge "  -replace ' *$',"s."
walk along the edges.s.
PS C:\>  "walk along the edge  " -replace ' *$',"s."
walk along the edges.s.
```

But I expected a more consistent behavior, like this:

```
$ echo "walk along the edge"   | sed "s/ *$/s./"
walk along the edges.
$ echo "walk along the edge "  | sed "s/ *$/s./"
walk along the edges.
$ echo "walk along the edge  " | sed "s/ *$/s./"
walk along the edges.
```

This is consistent between PS v7.2.5 and 4.1, both on Windows.
Referencing standard GNU sed on RHEL-flavored linux, if that matters.
I tried some parenthesis to "force" grouping, and escaping the dollar sign, to no avail.

How do I force the entire matching expression to be evaluated as one big match, in powershell?

Adding an extra space (or using the + metacharacter rather than *) is not quite what is required:

```
PS C:\>  "walk along the edge   " -replace '  *$',"s."
walk along the edges.
PS C:\>  "walk along the edge"   -replace '  *$',"s."
walk along the edge
```

Although it solves all the cases where there *is* a space, it fails for the case where there is not a space.

Comment: Due to the `*` quantifier it also matches an empty string at the end of the line. This is somewhat counter-intuitive behavior, as one would assume that the first match had already consumed all available characters.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369618/why-do-regex-engines-allow-automatically-attempt-matching-at-the-end-of-the-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a boundary before the spaces and this returns correctly every time.

```
PS C:\Users\TMTech> "walk along the edge"   -replace '\b *$',"s."
walk along the edges.

PS C:\Users\TMTech> "walk along the edge "  -replace '\b *$',"s."
walk along the edges.

PS C:\Users\TMTech> "walk along the edge  " -replace '\b *$',"s."
walk along the edges.
```

Comment: Except when there is already a point at the end of the input phrase... But maybe that is desired.

Comment: That was nowhere in their requirement.

Comment: I think this is also the most "semantic" option. I had not thought of the case where a period exists already in the source string. To cover that as well:  `-replace '\b[. ]*$',"s."`

Answer (score 2):

You can force the single match by capturing the preceding character, like this:

```
"walk along the edge      "   -replace '(\S) *$','$1s.'
```