# Difference in re.sub in Python between version 3.6 and 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I just found strange (for me) difference in regular expression module in Python3. Is it some change between version 3.6.9 and 3.10.6 that I overlooked? In fact, it looks like regression to me.

Code:

```
import re
RE_IP = re.compile(r'[0-9]*$')
RE_IP.sub('0', '1.2.3.4')
```

result in Python 3.10.6 is `'1.2.3.00'` and in Python 3.6.9: `'1.2.3.0'`
The latter result is what I expect.

Comment: Not sure about this, but the following might be relevant: "Changed in version 3.7: Empty matches for the pattern are replaced when adjacent to a previous non-empty match."

Comment: unable to reproduce in https://rextester.com/l/python3_online_compiler ... but maybew thats not really 3.6 ... the other two comments look more relevant

Comment: I got same in 3.7.9 for what it's worth: `'1.2.3.00'`

Comment: @j1-lee Thank you. This really looks like the answer. I must say that this change is quite containtutive.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I tried it in Ubuntu 18.04: Python 3.6.9 (default, Jun 29 2022, 11:45:57)

Comment: @PeterWood yep, j1-lee is right. It is change in Python 3.7. It is quite old project that I am updating to current Ubuntu LTS now :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your regular exception matches empty string. You can make it and it will work fine. I'll try to find documentation changes and update my answer.

```
import re
RE_IP = re.compile(r'[0-9]+$')
RE_IP.sub('0', '1.2.3.4')
```

UPD:

According to the comments by @j1-lee

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713570/re-sub-replacement-text-doubles-replacement-on-python-3-7) and this change
"Changed in version 3.7: Empty matches for the pattern are replaced when adjacent to a previous non-empty match." explains the changes