# regex replace in powershell command duplicates characters: a bug in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

Say I want to rename files in a file tree and add an extension. I used this powershell command, but there is a bug: it adds the extension twice; why ? how to correct this ?

```
 get-childitem * -recurse -exclude *.h | where { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
     rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace '(\w*)','$1.h'} -whatif
```

Comment: If you just want to **add** an extension you could simply do `-newname ($_.name + '.h')`

Comment: `*` matches 0 chars. Use `+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That was the right thing ! and it is logical.

Comment: @Olaf the command does not work as expected, I lose the whole filename

Comment: I think @Olaf meant `-newname { $_.name + '.h' }` (a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375), as in your own attempt). Applied to a simplified version of your command: `get-childitem  -file -recurse -exclude *.h  |  rename-item -newname { $_.name  + '.h' } -WhatIf`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52351217/45375

Comment: In every case I've seen involving regex, it's the implementer, not the regex system ;)