# Including Whitespace At the End of a Line When Regex Substituting a Character To the End of a Line

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

Say I have the following (where `<space>` indicates an actual whitespace character)

```
Line 1
Line 2<space>
Line 3
Line 4<space>
Line 5
```

and I wanted it to be

```
Line 1/
Line 2/
Line 3/
Line 4/
Line 5/
```

I initially thought that maybe `s/\s*$/\//g` would work but then I ended up with the following as the solution

```
Line 1/
Line 2//
Line 3/
Line 4//
Line 5/
```

I can't think of a way to include the case where there is a whitespace character at the end that I want replaced.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @Nick I am using the text replacement in vim

Comment: `:%s/\s*$/\//g` does *exactly* what you expect on all the Vim versions I have at hand: https://i.imgur.com/8YwlwCB.gif

Answer (score 1):

`\s*$` can match a string ending in a space twice; once to capture the actual space character, and again to match the end of string (see for example [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351217/why-do-some-regex-engines-match-twice-in-a-single-input-string)). This is why you are getting two replacements on the strings ending in space. To avoid this problem, use a positive lookbehind for a non-space character; that prevents the end of string that is preceded by a space being matched again. In normal regex you would match with:

```regex
(?<=\S)\s*$
```

and replace with a `/`. [Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/61I98U/1/).

In `vim` you can use the `\zs` marker to define the start of the match e.g.

```
:%s/\S\zs\s*$/\//
```