# Regex to extract last elements from a list

Tags: regex

I can have as input the following list:
`V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9, V10`

I would need a regex that extracts the last 3 elements from the list above.
So after applying the regex the list should look like: `V8, V9, V10`

I have tried this regex [`/^.*(?=((,.*){3})$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/ORrooa/1), it seems I'm getting close but I don't understand why when replacing with `$1` I get the output duplicated.

Can anyone help me with an explanation? If I'm able to understand why this happens I should be able to correct it.

Comment: Please add the regex into the question body.

Comment: honestly, yes, a regex can do that, but it's very awkward doing with a regex, is there a particular reason this *must* me done with a regex, or would something simpler not do?

Comment: Can you also post the replacement code, please? Are you using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should work

```
/^.*, ([^,]+, [^,]+, [^,]+)$/
```

- `^` Match the beginning of the string
- `.*` Match 0 or more characters, taking as many as posible
- `,`  Match a comma followed by a space
- `(` Begin capture
- `[^,]+` Match one or more not commas
- This gets repeated so we can match the last 3 elements
- `)` End capture
- `$` Match end of string

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *extract* the last three comma-separated values using

```js
[^\s,][^,]*(?=(?:,[^,]*){0,2}$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cdYOez/1). *Details*:

- `[^\s,]` - a char other than whitespace and comma
- `[^,]*` - any zero or more chars other than a comma
- `(?=(?:,[^,]*){0,2}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero, one or two occurrences of a comma and then zero or more non-comma chars till the end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

You get you match replaced twice because of a known issue, see [Why do some regex engines match .* twice in a single input string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52351217/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you should use `?:` instead of `?=`, then you will get `, V8, V9, V10`

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+){2})$` will return the same without preceding comma `V8, V9, V10`

Answer (score 0):

The captured part in your pattern has 3 comma's because the lookahead assertion repeats 3 times a pattern `(,.*){3}` starting with a comma

There is not language specified, but depending on the supported regex flavor, you could also use a single capture group for the last 3 values between 2 comma's:

```
^.*(?<!\S)([^,\n]*(?:,[^,\n]*){2})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*` Match the whole line
- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^,\n]*` Optionally match any char except `,` or a newline
  - `(?:,[^,\n]*){2}` Repeat 2 times matching the `,` and optional chars other than `,` or a newline
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z99T0y/1)

Or as an alternative, split on `,`  take the last 3 elements from the collection and join them back again with the same delimiter.

An example using JavaScript:

```js
const str = "V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9, V10";
console.log(str.split(", ").slice(-3).join(", "));
```